# Assembly - number from stack

Tags: c, assembly, att, x87

This is part of my code:

```
.data

.text
.global fx
fx:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp

    finit
    fldl 8(%ebp)
```

I call this function from C. Since 8 byte there should be value that I called, am I right? But what I see in gdb is:

```
(gdb) info float
=>R7: Valid   0x3bf2bd04000000000000 +1.00272590169167575e-312  
  R6: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R5: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R4: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R3: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R2: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R1: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R0: Empty   0x00000000000000000000

Status Word:         0x3802      DE                                    
                       TOP: 7
Control Word:        0x037f   IM DM ZM OM UM PM
                       PC: Extended Precision (64-bits)
                       RC: Round to nearest
Tag Word:            0x3fff
Instruction Pointer: 0x00:0x0804849b
Operand Pointer:     0x00:0xffffcbb0
Opcode:              0xdd45
```

This is right after fldl 8(%ebp). My friend made the same program and it worked. What did I do wrong?

And below my full C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float fx(float x);
float gx(float x);

int main(){

float x;
printf("Podaj wartosc x: ");
scanf("%f",&x);
float wynik1 = fx(x);
float wynik2 = gx(x);

printf("\nWynik funkcji f(x)=%f\nWynik funkcji g(x)=%f\n",wynik1,wynik2);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading a double (`fldl`) instead of a float (`flds`).

Comment: That was so simple... Thanks!